# Online Bank Statements Accepted for Japan visa?

Tags: visas, japan, proof-provenance-of-funds

Is online bank statements accepted for Japan visa?

Comment: The Japanese Embassy website in the U.K. https://www.uk.emb-japan.go.jp/en/visa/pdf/sightseeing,%20visiting_friends.pdf states original documents are required. AFAIK this is typically interpreted to mean on original bank paper (ie traditional printed statements) or online statements certified by the bank concerned.

Comment: It depends on which country you’re applying from. In the USA banks don’t certify bank statements (at least Bank of America doesn’t). The statement if printed online or received in the mail are considered certified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide a hard copy, ideally attested by the bank. The application process for Japan visa is mostly offline, so you will need a hard copy.